# Zooming on firefox breaks SVG loaded inside an iframe

Tags: firefox, iframe, svg

I have a div with a specific size, which contains an iframe, sized 100%. This iframe loads an SVG-file that doesn't have height and width set, or is also sized 100%.

When zooming in IE or Chrome, everything is fine.
When zooming in Firefox, the following seems to happen:

The div is scaled up according to the zoom factor. The iframe is also scaled up because it fills out the scaled up div with its 100% size. The SVG in the iframe seems to be scaled up to fill the iframe, THEN the zoom factor is also applied to it so that it is now actually bigger than the iframe.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hz5ue94c/2/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<iframe class="frame" frameborder="0" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Is there a way to stop Firefox from zooming the SVG?

Edit: I'm not sure if the problem is with the iframe or the SVG. If I have SVG directly in the div, the problem doesn't seem to occur, but I need to load the file into an iframe.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Download the source code to Firefox, figure out where https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843480 is occurring and fix it.